# Union of all sets such that $\left\{ c-b , b-a \right\}=\left\{ 1789 , 1830\right\}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If we consider all sets $\left\{ a;b;c\right\}$ such that $a;b;c\ge0$ and $a<b<c$ and
$\left\{ c-b;b-a\right\}=\left\{ 1789;1830\right\}$. Can we say that the set of all positive integers is the union of such disjointed sets ?

I was thinking about doing an induction, starting by $0$ we must have $\left\{ 0;1789;1789+1830\right\}$ or $\left\{ 0;1830;1789+1830\right\}$. Then we must have $\left\{ 1;1790;1790+1830\right\}$ or $\left\{ 1;1831;1789+1831\right\}$. And so on but i do not know if this works. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: A revolutionary question...

Comment: @JeanMarie, only for the French :)

Answer (score 0):

So, you’re asking about the set of all positive integers and then write that $a,b,c$ can be equal to $0$, and start your first triple with $0$. It doesn’t really matter since the distance between numbers is what matters, not their actual values. I will also start with $0$.

Assume that the set of all admissible numbers is the disjoint union of such triples. We will call a number “$a$” if it’s the smallest in its triple, “$b$” if it’s the middle one, or “$c$” otherwise.

All numbers from $0$ to $1788$ are undoubtedly “$a$”s. We don’t know quite how their “$b$”s are looking yet, but what we know for sure is that all numbers from $1789+1830$ to $1789+1830+1788$ are their corresponding “$c$”s. There are $1830$ numbers in between $1788$ and $1789+1830$. $1789$ of them are the “$b$”s for $0,…,1788$. The rest $1830-1789=41$ are “$a$”s.

Where are the $41$ “$b$”s of those “$a$”s? Consider the smallest of these “$a$”s. It is $41+1789=1830$ numbers away from the nearest free number. So clearly the last $41$ of those $1830$ numbers are “$a$”s for some new triples. (And the first $1789$ of those $1830$ numbers are “$b$”s for the numbers $0,…,1788$ in the natural order. The number $1789$ can be a “$b$” only for “$0$”, $1790$ - only for $1$, etc. I believe, we don’t really need this fact though.)

So what did we get yet? $1789+1830+1788$ first numbers are distributed, then $41$ “$b$” go which are of the from $a+1830$. It means that there are $41$ “$c$”s there later in the numbers row of the from $b+1789$. There are $1748$ numbers in between those $41$ “$a$” and “$b$”s. They are all clearly “$a$”s.

Their “$c$”s are later in the numbers row. They are equal to $a+1789+1830$ for the corresponding “$a$”s. There are $41+1830$ numbers between these “$a$”s and “$c$”s. $41$ of them are “$c$”s for the earlier $41$ triples. $1830-1748=82$ are “$a$”s for some new triples.

Their “$b$”s are after all the numbers which are already distributed, and they are of the from $a+1830$. The pattern repeats itself fully. The only thing that changes is the number of these “$b$”s with which we start. They went from $0$ to $41$ to $82$. All multiples of $41$. So in order to succeed it must be that $1789$ is divisible by $41$ but it’s a prime number.

We’ve got a contradiction so the positive integers aren’t the disjointed union of these triples.

Comment: i do not clearly see how did you manage to prove that the smallest of these "a" is $1830$. For me the smallest of these "a" could clearly be "1789 ? For exemple is you take $1830$ for $a=0$ then $1831$ for $a=1$ and so on your $41$"a"  will be integers from $1789$ to $1829$ ?